# Conflict between set layers and useasboundingbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using `extra ticks` and want to draw the extra tick (like all the other ticks) behind the axis. Hence, I use `\pgfplotsset{set layers}`. However, this option is apparently not compatible with the `\useasboundingbox` command, as I get the error message `! Dimension too large. \pgfplotspointupperrightcorner ...f@x =-32000.0pt`.

Is there a simple fix to combine both commands? If not, how can I remove extra whitespace around the plot?

Image with extra y tick at 1.1 (and tick behind axis line) but too much whitespace around:
[image: image with extra tick but too much white space around]

Images (zoom) without and with layers:

[image: image with without layers]
[image: image (zoom) with layers]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{set layers}% <-- conflict with useasboundigbox, needed that extra y ticks are behind axis line
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\useasboundingbox (-0.65,-0.45) rectangle (6.85,5.85); % <-- conflict with set layers, needed to reduce extra space around plot

\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    extra y ticks={1.1},
    ]
    \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2.2,2)};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Move the `\useasboundingbox` line behind `\end{axis}`.

Comment: Is it always better to have `\useasboundingbox` at the very end or are there some drawbacks?

Comment: I'd say yes, but I'm not Till Tantau.

Comment: If you include a picture with `\node {\includegraphics[]{image.pdf}};`, you need to place `\useasboundingbox` before it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why there is a conflict in your code. But here are two workarounds for your example.

You can replace `\useasboundingbox` by `path` and put the `axis` in a `pgfinterruptboundingbox` environment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (-0.65,-0.45) rectangle (6.85,5.85);% \path instead \useasboundingbox
    \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% <-added
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            extra y ticks={1.1},
            ]
            \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2.2,2)};  
        \end{axis}
    \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% <- added
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you change the order of the `axis` environment and the `\useasboundingbox` command. But then you have to add a `\pgfresetboundingbox` command *before* `\useasboundingbox`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{set layers}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        extra y ticks={1.1},
        ]
        \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2.2,2)};  
    \end{axis}
    \pgfresetboundingbox% <- added
    \useasboundingbox (-0.65,-0.45) rectangle (6.85,5.85);% behind axis and \pgfresetboundingbox
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```